# Extended chest pump - 1 and a half days

Tags: exercise, muscle, muscle-soreness, muscle-recovery, chest

After a 6 month break after finishing a 10 week (5 day/week) fitness program, I restarted it last week.

Last week I only went to gym 2 days out of five (Monday & Friday) and this week all the way Monday to Friday. My routine is cardio (treadmill Tuesday and Thursday) and other major muscle groups in the rest of the days.

After doing chest & back on Wednesday I felt a bit of soreness in my pectoral muscles and a normal pump in my chest. After Thrusday's cardio program (20 mintues on a treadmill - aprox. 1.8 miles, I pushed myself a bit) my chest became very pumped (almost twice in size than before Wednesday).

I wouldn't worry about it, but my chest has been pumped like this for about a day and a half now and I've never experienced this before.

The pumps I had the last time I did this program were normal and didn't last more than a day (the day of the exercise), but this one started increasing in intesity one day after (Thursday) and keeps going until today (still pumped).

I'm not sure if this is a reason to worry, but I've never experienced anything like this before and I did make some web-searches but haven't found any details regarding "extended" pumps.

I also started doing a 15-16 hour fasting cycle, I'm not sure if this information is useful or it has any implication to my condition.

Has anyone else had a similar experience and/or should a pump last so long?

Comment: Apparently what you have to do is stretch if your muscles are tight. That did the trick and now the pump is gone.